# Is there a way to view iTunes Store purchase history on a regular internet browser?

Tags: itunes-store

Is there a way to view iTunes Store purchases without using iTunes? My bank account shows several music purchases I'm not aware of and I would like to verify them but currently don't have access to my main computer.

Comment: Are you talking about music or apps?

Comment: Music because it says on my bank account.

Comment: Also, i dont have access to itunes here at work.

Comment: Do you have an iPhone? You can see all purchased music from the `Purchased` tab. However, it's not very helpful, as there's no obvious way to sort by date, which is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

no you can't but you can you report a problem to list your purchases

https://reportaproblem.apple.com